# How to reset MongoDB replica set settings

Tags: mongodb

I want to start over the configurations of replica, is it possible? How to reset it?

In [group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/GB4IZXNnsak) people saying to remove the database content, but are there any work around?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to keep the data, but start outside a replica set, just restart the mongod process without the `--replSet` and on a different port.  That will give you a standalone mongod.

To be completely sure that the replica set configuration is gone from the instance, make sure that the `local.system.replset` collection is empty.

Once that is done, and you are happy with your standalone instance, you can then restart with a different `--replSet` argument and go through the replica set configuration process again:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Set+Configuration

The other option, as you mention, is to remove all the data files and start completely from scratch.

Comment: //start server on different port than assigned but with same Db folder . connect via mongoi client to new port :
use local
db.system.replset.remove({"_id":"replset"}) //change replset in quotes to your name?
db.system.replset.find()
db.adminCommand({shutdown : 1})
//then restart on other port

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to remove any database files in order to reset the configuration of your replica set.

To reset the configuration, make sure every node in your replica set is stopped.  Then delete the "local" database for every node.

Once you are confident all nodes are not running and the `local` database are gone, start the mongod process again (of course using the `--replSet` flag).  Then run `rs.initiate()`.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to mongo shell on **Secondary servers**
2. Stop the **secondary servers** by using below command :

```code
   use admin
   db.shutdownServer()
```

3. Go to Linux shell- on **secondary servers** and type below command :

   `sudo service mongod stop`

Starting the MongoDB replication -

- Go to Linux shell - on **secondary servers** and type below command :

  `sudo service mongod start`

Starting the MongoDB replication -

- Go to **Primary Server** and type below commands to start the replication :

a] `rs.initiate()`

b] `rs.add("Secondar -1:port no")`

c] `rs.add("Secondary-2:port no")`

d] `rs.add({ "_id" : 3, "host" : "Hidden_member:port no", "priority" : 0,  "hidden" : true })`

e] `rs.status()`

For more information, Please check the below link : http://www.tutorial-points.com/2016/03/stopping-and-starting-mongodb.html

Comment: its not working for me when I connect use `mongo` command I have connect with rs:PRIMARY> now I want to remove replica set

Answer (score 4):

1. edit `/etc/mongod.conf` and comment out `replication: block`
2. `service mongod restart`
3. `mongo local --eval "db.dropDatabase()"`
4. `service mongod stop`
5. **on mongo primary :** `rs.add("this node")`
6. edit `/etc/mongod.conf` and uncomment the `replication: block`
7. `service mongod restart`

Your node will get added to the existing replica set and will start syncing to the existing primary